# Mostrar en un combobox un campo de dos tablas

Tags: c#, sql

en mi BDD tengo dos tablas "usuario" y "personas"

en un combobox quiero mostrar el campo "ci" que tiene la tabla "usuario", y el campo "nombre" que tien la tabla "personas"

gracias de antemano

```
 public void rec_usuario_emp(List<string> lista, ComboBox cmb)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.ToArray().Length; i++)
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string cadena = "select ci from usuario where ci = @ci";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ci", lista.ToArray().GetValue(i));
            SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                cmb.Items.Add(reader["ci"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                cmb.Items.Remove(lista.ToArray().GetValue(i));
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }



 private void cmbcedula_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> y = new List<string>();
        cslt.llenar_lst_emp(y);
        cslt.rec_usuario_emp(y, cmbcedula);
        cmbcedula.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CmbBoxItemStyle"];
    }
```

Solo muestra la cedula pero no el nombre

Comment: Hola @positiveSteven te aconsejo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder ayudarte. ¿Cuáles tecnologías usas?¿Qué llevas hecho? ¿Tienes snippets que nos puedan ayudar a ayudarte?

Comment: Hola, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y pueda ser respondida, considera compartir el código de lo que llevas hasta ahora

Comment: tu select solo trae un campo. Averigua sobre inner join y como traer mas de un campo

Comment: No ofreces información sobre las tablas utilizadas, ¿cómo podremos ayudarte a crear la consulta?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación entre `usuario` y `personas`? es el `ci`?